# Foundation 5 abide js check if date is before another date

Tags: javascript, forms, zurb-foundation

I'm using `zurb foundation 5` and `abide js` for checking my form. I must check if `DATE1` is before or equals to `DATE2`

How I can check if it is valid with `abidejs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is you can't really use abide for this. Abide does not facilitate the comparison you need to do with the dates to check if the one is greater or equal to the other. Some custom javascript can do that for you but you will find that abide will fight you for control of the error messages which means you are going to have scrap abide altogether and do all the error handling yourself.

Here is an illustration of what I mean:

HTML

```
<div class="panel">
  <form data-abide class="date-form">
    <div class="date-1">
      <label>Date 1</label>
      <input type="date">
      <small class="error">This is not a valid date.</small>
    </div>
    <div class="date-2">
      <label>Date 2</label>
      <input type="date">
      <small class="error">Date 2 must be a valid date and fall on or after date 1.</small>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
//lets do a check when one of the input values has changed
$('.date-form').on('change', '.date-1 input, .date-2 input', function() {
  //lets convert our dates to values we can do a comparison with
  date1 = Date.parse($('.date-1 input').val());
  date2 = Date.parse($('.date-2 input').val());

  //lets check that both values are valid numbers
  if ($.isNumeric(date1) && $.isNumeric(date2)) {
    //lets check if date 2 is not greater or equal to date one and throw an error
    if (date1 > date2) {
      //we have a problem add error class to date-2 for error message
      $('.date-2').addClass('error');
    }
  }
});
```

This will fight with abide. Here is a fiddle to illustrate it http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fiKFc.

So long answer is still you can't really use abide for this. Sorry.

Comment: yes I imagined there was no other way, I've also used a similar solution. Thanks you!